# How was this Python Turtle graphic made?

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics

My friend showed me this amazing image that she made using Python's inbuilt [Turtle module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) and challenged me to find out how it was made. She gave me one hint: the image was produced with 10 lines of code.

[image: 10 Line Turtle Graphic]

From my question you probably already know that I have no clue. I've tried a whole heap of things, but I don't know how she made a filled in circle with *such* detailed patterns in only 10 lines. I've given up on figuring it out myself, and my friend won't tell me, so anyone who can produce 10 lines that make a similar image gets all the credit for figuring it out :P

Note: I'm not sure if this is appropriate for StackOverflow, so I'm happy to ask elsewhere (let me know), but this *was* made using Python code, so I thought someone on a programming forum might have the experience to work it out.

Comment: If you start somewhere and go forward 10 steps and then in a loop turn 179 degrees and then got forward 10 steps you will end up with something like this.  Then you just need to find out how many steps and what size turn matches this picture.

Comment: Maybe you could find some hints [here](https://michael0x2a.com/blog/turtle-examples).

Comment: Those "detailed patterns" look like they're just an artifact of the discrete nature of computer graphics. I'm not sure what the term is; it might qualify as [moiré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). In any case, it looks like they just drew a bunch of closely-spaced lines coming out of the image center and the patterns were an automatic consequence of doing so.

Comment: Your friends _hint_ really ain't helpful. Does she realize how much code you can cram into 10 lines! Python does have semi-colons.

Comment: I create heaven with 2 line ! `from nonuniverse import heaven; heaven.build_pls('Bahama','Tokyo')` Did you know how much line include whole `turtle` library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe your looking for:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.Pen()
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     t.forward(100)
...     t.backward(100)
...     t.left(79)
...
```

output:

[image]

It is a miniature example of the output you showed in your question.
Basicly the way that is works is that each time the turtle pen goes forward and comes back, the pen turns. This is repeated multiple times, to create those 'detailed patterns'. Also, your friend may have mislead you a bit, as this is much shorter than ten lines.

Comment: Wow - even less lines than my answer! Thanks for spending the time :)

Answer (score 2):

After some tuning, I find this, which, I think, is very close to the image, with exact 10 lines.

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed(0)
for i in range(632):
    bob.forward(200)
    bob.right(1)
    bob.forward(100)
    bob.setpos(0,0)
    bob.left(1.57)
turtle.done()
```

[image: first try]

**Edit:** There are more, draw with a single line, get this, which I have not expected:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed(0)
for i in range(1080):
    bob.forward(300)
    bob.setpos(0,0)
    bob.left(0.33333)
turtle.done()
```

[image: draw with lines]
And draw with a triangle:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.speed(0)
for i in range(720):
    bob.forward(50)
    bob.right(19)
    bob.forward(250)
    bob.setpos(0,0)
    bob.left(19.5)
turtle.done()
```

[image: draw with triangles]

Comment: Cool patterns! I didn't know how complex these artefacts could be :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @citaret and @JerryJeremiah's suggestions, I was able to put together something that produces similar results to the image, in less than 10 lines:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
mr_turtle = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
mr_turtle.speed(0)
for i in range(1800):
    mr_turtle.forward(300)
    mr_turtle.right(179.9)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Thanks guys!